# import a new angular module to my app-root

Tags: javascript, angular

i have create a new angular module

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'hero-detail',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="hero">
      <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
      <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
      <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class HeroDetailComponent {
hero: Hero;
}
```

and i'm trying to import it in my app-root module using the import statement

```
import { HeroDetail } from 'hero-detail';
```

but i get this error 
**"src/app/app.component.ts (2,28): Cannot find module 'hero-detail'."**

Comment: you can check the hero-detail Component path in relation to the app-module

Comment: at the same directory

Comment: they are in the same folder? are you sure you have the file name correct?

Comment: You realise that `'hero-detail'` means look up in node_modules? Unless you configured webpack to use aliases (which you didn't otherwise you would be skilled enough to fix it yourself anyway).

Answer (score 1):

this resolve it for me

```
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the right name of componenet

```
import { HeroDetailComponent } from 'hero-detail';
```